# Angular - Property 'NewPassword' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['NewPassword']

Tags: angular

In Angular-13 I am trying to implement Change Password. It has ASP.NET Core Web API as it's backend.

I have these codes:

auth.service:

```
mustChangePassword(NewPassword:string, ConfirmNewPassword:string){
  const data = {
    NewPassword:NewPassword,
    ConfirmNewPassword:ConfirmNewPassword
  }
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'auth/change-password', data);
}
```

component.ts:

```
export class ChangePasswordComponent implements OnInit {
  changePasswordForm!: FormGroup;
  isLoading = false;
  isSubmitted = false;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
    ) {
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    const formOptions: AbstractControlOptions = { validators: MustMatch('NewPassword', 'ConfirmNewPassword') };
    this.changePasswordForm = this.fb.group({
      NewPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(80)]],
      ConfirmNewPassword: ['', [Validators.required]]
    }, formOptions);
  }

  get f() { return this.changePasswordForm.controls; }

  onSubmit(){
    this.isSubmitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.changePasswordForm.invalid) {
          return;
      }

    const formData = this.changePasswordForm.getRawValue();
      const NewPassword = formData.NewPassword;
      const ConfirmNewPassword = formData.ConfirmNewPassword;

    this.isLoading = true;
    this.authService.mustChangePassword(NewPassword, ConfirmNewPassword).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.toastr.success(res.message);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.toastr.error(error.message);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

component.html:

```
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="login-box-msg">You are only one step a way from your new password, recover your password now.</p>
    <form [formGroup]="changePasswordForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="password" formControlName="NewPassword" placeholder="New Password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': isSubmitted && f.NewPassword.errors }" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="isSubmitted && f.NewPassword.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.NewPassword.errors.required">Password is required</div>
          <div *ngIf="f.NewPassword.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 6 characters</div>
          <div *ngIf="f.NewPassword.errors.maxlength">Password cannot be more than 80 characters</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="password" formControlName="ConfirmNewPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': isSubmitted && f.confirmNewPassword.errors }" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="isSubmitted && f.ConfirmNewPassword.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.ConfirmNewPassword.errors.required">Confirm Password is required</div>
          <div *ngIf="f.ConfirmNewPassword.errors.mustMatch">Passwords must match</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" [disabled]="isLoading">
            <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
            Change password
          </button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <a [routerLink]="['/auth']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-lock mr-2"></i>Login</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I got a strange error in the HTML:

> Property 'NewPassword' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['NewPassword']

It highlights NewPassword, required, minlength and maxlength.

**I did ['NewPassword'], but error not still resolved.**

The same thing happen to 'ConfirmNewPassword'

I've been using this for a long time, why the error now.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f['yourFieldName'].errors?.['yourErrorType']
```

so, for example:

```
*ngIf="f.ConfirmNewPassword.errors.mustMatch"
```

becomes:

```
*ngIf="f['ConfirmNewPassword'].errors?.['mustMatch']"
```

It's an Angular 13 thingie now.

Comment: this solution works well on version of Angular 14.2.7

Answer (score 0):

So in your Html where you are doing `f.NewPassword.errors` instead of that, do the following (as per your requirement)

`f['NewPassword'].errors`

`f['NewPassword'].errors && f['NewPassword'].errors['required']`.

Answer (score 0):

In latest Angular I faced this issue with `ngOnChanges`.

Like `changes.someField.currentValue` also triggered this error - `Property 'value' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['value']`

and it was easily muted with `tsconfig.json` change

```
"compilerOptions": {
//
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
```

Disclaimer: I think `SimpleChanges` values doesn't need to be `['square-braked']` because we listen for `@Inputs` which are already declared in class, they are not a dynamic values which accidentally be lost in some way inside ngOnChanges class.